Reconciling Maimonides' Interpretation of Theodicy in the Book of Job: Eliphaz vs. Elihu
A question has been on my mind, and I would appreciate your opinion.
While studying chapter 23 of the third book of the Moreh Nevukhim, Rambam (Maimonides) seems to acknowledge the traditional view of theodicy represented by Eliphaz in the Book of Job (Job 4:7-8), where suffering is seen as a direct retribution for sins:

Remember, I pray thee, who ever perished, being innocent? Or where
were the upright cut off? According to what I have seen, those who
plow iniquity and sow trouble, reap the same.

However, he also seems to give credit to Elihu's perspective, presented in Job 32-37, which suggests that suffering can be a test or a divine lesson, and that the ways of God are often beyond our understanding. Elihu states in Job 33:14:

For God speaks in one way, and in two, though man does not perceive it

and further in Job 34:10-12, he insists on God's justice:

Therefore, listen to me, you men of understanding: far be it from God
to do wickedness, and from the Almighty to commit iniquity. For
according to the work of a man, He will repay him, and according to
his ways, He will make it befall him. Of a truth, God will not do
wickedly, and the Almighty will not pervert justice.

This appears to be a significant nuance compared to Eliphaz's view. Is Maimonides deviating from the Jewish tradition by incorporating Elihu's perspective?
I must admit, I am a bit lost, and most of the commentaries I have seen on this haven't helped. How can Rambam deviate from what he considers the Jewish view of Hashgacha (Divine Providence)?
Thank you for your insights.

Welcome. Indeed, the Book of Job provides several contrasting views on the problem of suffering. In my understanding, unlike Christianity, Rabbinic Judaism does not require theological credo or some form of philosophical Orthod-Doxy, unlike Halachic practices. Therefore, all proposed theodicies find some form of support in Rabbinic sources, and they all are utilized in Rabbinic discourse. If you were presented with one view and considered it to be exclusive, you might want to research other approaches too.

R. Dr. Mordechai Z. Cohen has an essay titled "Maimonides Disagreement with 'the Torah' in His Interpretation of Job" (in Zutot 2004, pp. 66-78) that explores this topic. You can download it here

@Deuteronomy thank you so much. It is perfect. This is by far the best explanation I've read on this topic. I owe you. Thank you!

My pleasure, glad to be of assistance! Might I recommend that you compose a brief summary and submit it as an answer to your own question? It may benefit others that have been bothered by the same question(s) :) All the best
